# excel create graph file size growing every day

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet that has :

```
Date        Size(bytes)
8/8/2017    6486706098
8/7/2017    6474192424
8/6/2017    6469526545
8/4/2017    6451125975
8/3/2017    6437334288
8/2/2017    6426620252
6/6/2017    5845632361
6/5/2017    5877592539
6/4/2017    5875605176
6/3/2017    5873370398
6/2/2017    5883223462
6/1/2017    5868480232
5/31/2017   5854009368
5/30/2017   5837097708
5/29/2017   5836226473
5/28/2017   5835186829
5/27/2017   5831554057
5/26/2017   5824822842
5/25/2017   5805244632
5/24/2017   5795580695
5/22/2017   5775056353
5/21/2017   5773851412

........
1/15/2017   4325428342
1/14/2017   4325430642
1/13/2017   4325428369
1/12/2017   4325429979
```

How to create a graph :
y axis (size of the file)
x axis days

Thanks, your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use defined names and create a dynamic range for the defined name.  Then graph your defined names.

Assuming Columns A and B for your data and header row in row 1

```
Defined Name Axis_X
=$A$2:INDEX(A:A,COUNT(A:A)+1,1)

Defined Name Axis_Y1
=$B$2:INDEX(B:B,COUNT(B:B)+1,1)

'The +1 in the formula above is to account for header row.  if your header row is more than just the first row, you would need to increase 1 accordingly.
```

Then when creating your graph, used the defined names instead of defining a range on the spreadsheet with the mouse.